# track changes on certain field in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i am trying record changes done on certain field and display them as messages threads but i can't display messages threads although i have done steps in documentation 
here is simple code i test on

models.py

```py
from openerp import models, fields, api


class model_test(models.Model):

    _name = "testt.model_test"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
    testt = fields.Char(string="test_text",track_visibility='onchange')
```

views.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

    <act_window id="test_main_act" name="testt" res_model="testt.model_test" view_mode="tree,form" >

    </act_window>

    <menuitem id="test_module_root" name="test module" action="test_main_act"/>

        <record id="test_list" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name"> test form</field>
            <field name="model">testt.model_test</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <header>
                        <button name="add_one" type="object" string="Add one" />

                    </header>
                    <sheet>
                        <field name="testt" />
                    </sheet>

                </form>

                 <div class="oe_chatter">
                    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
                    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                </div>
            </field>

        </record>

        <record id="test_list" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name"> test list</field>
            <field name="model">testt.model_test</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="testt"></field>
                </tree>
            </field>

        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

then the result isn't what i expect 
[unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S073y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move your `oe_chatter` code block to within your `<form>` tags.

This block:

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
    <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
    <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>
```

to be moved to before your closing `</form>` tag.

---

**EDIT:** Missed this out the first time

This is a common error, so just be careful the next time.

Your record id for **form** view and **tree** view are the same - `test_list`. Change one of them to something else and you will be fine.

Comment: i have forgotten to get it back sorry i was tasting its effect if it was after </form> but no change in both cases

Comment: thanks a lot my friend ^_^ it worked i just changed form view id

Comment: but the label for the input has disappeared i don't know why ??

Comment: For that one, please wrap your `<field name="testt" />` within `<group>` tags. So, `<sheet><group><field name="testt"/></group></sheet>`. :)

Comment: thanks again it has worked. i need more study about those tags